# Angular Jasmine error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have written an angular test using Jasmine and getting an error on event piece of code since its not mocked correctly. Can you please let me know where i am going wrong

The error that i am getting is

TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

in this method

it('should trigger change method on select value change',fakeAsync(() => {}

I have tried to mock the event object like this the test class

```
const event = { event: { target: { value: 42 }}};
```

test

```
import { Mock } from 'ts-mocks';


fdescribe('TestTypeComponent', () => {
  let component: TestTypeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestTypeComponent>;
  let mockTestTypeService;
  let mockCommonStore;

  const testTypeModel = TestTypeModelObjectMock;
  const event = { event: { target: { value: 42 }}};
  const setupComponent = () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestTypeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  };


  beforeEach (() => {
    mockCommonStore = new Mock<CommonStore>({
      setSelectedTestType: () => void(1),
      getSelectedTestType: () => of(1)
    });

    mockTestTypeService = new Mock<TestTypeService>({
      getTestTypes: () => of(testTypeModel)
    });

     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [TestTypeComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: TestTypeService,  useFactory: () =>   mockTestTypeService.Object },
        { provide: CommonStore, useFactory: () =>   mockCommonStore.Object }

      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    setupComponent();
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should trigger change method on select value change',fakeAsync(() => {
     setupComponent();
      var select = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#selectTestType'))
        .triggerEventHandler("change", {});
        component.onSelectingTestType(event);
        flush();
      fixture.whenStable().then(res => {
        expect(component.commonStore.setSelectedTestType).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
    }));
});
```

Component

```
    onSelectingTestType(event: any) {
        let typeId = 0;
        if (event.target.value !== 'All') {
          typeId = +event.target.value;
        }
        this.commonStore.setSelectedTestType(typeId);
```

CommonStore

```
    private selectedAccountType = new Subject<number>();
    
      setSelectedAccountType(selectedTypeId: number) {
        this.selectedAccountType.next(selectedTypeId);
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mock your object like this:

```
const event = { target: { value: 42 }};
```

Otherwise you have to do, `event.event`.

---

Another issue is your `triggerEventHandler`. The 2nd argument should be the event object you created above:

```
.triggerEventHandler("change", event);
```

This way you should not have to call `component.onSelectingTestType(event);`, because the component already calls that from the template (I guess).

Also you should not use `fakeAsync`. Only when you are really faking the timer. You can use the native js `await/async` pattern.

Another point is that you should use `useValue` in the provider. Which will bring the complete test to this:

```
fdescribe('TestTypeComponent', () => {
  let component: TestTypeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestTypeComponent>;
  let mockTestTypeService;
  let mockCommonStore;

  const testTypeModel = TestTypeModelObjectMock;
  const event = { target: { value: 42 } };
  const setupComponent = () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestTypeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  };
  
  beforeEach (() => {
    mockCommonStore = new Mock<CommonStore>({
      setSelectedTestType: () => void(1),
      getSelectedTestType: () => of(1)
    });

    mockTestTypeService = new Mock<TestTypeService>({
      getTestTypes: () => of(testTypeModel)
    });

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [TestTypeComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: TestTypeService,  useValue: mockTestTypeService },
        { provide: CommonStore, useValue: mockCommonStore }

      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    setupComponent();
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should trigger change method on select value change', async () => {
    setupComponent();
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#selectTestType'))
      .triggerEventHandler("change", event);
    await fixture.whenStable();
    expect(component.commonStore.setSelectedTestType).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thats the first thing i had tried :). I am still getting the same error. I tried that once again after your response

Comment: I tried directly assigning it  component.onSelectingAccountType({ event: { target: { value: 42 }}});

Comment: Not sure why its not able to take it. I also tried calling the  fixture.detectChanges();

Comment: is this mocking correct ? setSelectedTestType: () => void(1),

Comment: Unfortunately the same error again. I am having doubt if the mock is correct as the method has no return .Its void type. But i am setting parameter in the void because it is giving me syntax error that void expects an expression

Comment: This is my template code  <select id="selectAccountType" class="form-select col-sm-10" (change)="onSelectingTestType($event)">

Comment: ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', '<toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got undefined.
Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalled()', '; Zone:', 'ProxyZone', '; Task:', 'Promise.then', '; Value:', Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got undefined.
Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalled()
Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got undefined.

Comment: it('should trigger change method on select value change',async function()  {
     setupComponent();
     await  fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#selectAccountType'))
        .triggerEventHandler("change", event);
        //component.onSelectingAccountType({ event: { target: { value: 42 }}});
        fixture.detectChanges();
      //  flush();
      fixture.whenStable().then(res => {
        expect(component.commonStore.setSelectedAccountType(1)).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
    });

Comment: changed the mock to this  setSelectedTestType(selectedTypeId : number) {}, But no difference

Comment: @Tom updated with an entire implementation